# Replace blanks in datasets with value in r

Tags: r

Apologies as I thought there would be a very obvious answer but I can't find anything on the net...

I often get very large datasets where missing values are blank e.g. (in short)

```
#Some description of the dataset
#cover x number of lines
31   3213 313   64    63
31   3213 313   64    63
31   3213 313   64    63
31   3213 313   64    63
31   3213 313   64    63
12   178        190   865
532  31   6164  68
614       131   864   808
```

I would like to replace all the blanks by, for example, -999. If I use read table such that

```
dat = read.table('file.txt',skip=2)
```

I get the error message

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
line 6 did not have 5 elements
```

I could open the file as a data frame and do

```
dat = data.frame('file.txt',skip=2)
is.na(rad1) = which(rad1 == '')
```

but I don't know if it would work because I don't know how to skip the top 2 lines when reading a dataframe (e.g. the equivalent of "skip") and I couldn't find the answer either anywhere. Could anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Your data is in fixed width format, so you should read it with `read.fwf()` instead of `read.table()`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you know the widths of each column then you can use `read.fwf`

e.g.

```
> dat <- read.fwf('temp.txt', skip=2, widths=c(5,5,6,6,6))
> dat
   V1   V2   V3  V4  V5
1  31 3213  313  64  63
2  31 3213  313  64  63
3  31 3213  313  64  63
4  31 3213  313  64  63
5  31 3213  313  64  63
6  12  178   NA 190 865
7 532   31 6164  68  NA
8 614   NA  131 864 808
```

Although it's easy to replace `NA` values with any value you want, that's just a bad idea, because R has many great way of dealing with NA values.

For example, to take the mean of column two, use:

```
mean(dat$V2, na.rm=TRUE)
[1] 163.4286
```

R has other functions to deal with missing data. For example, you can use `na.omit()` to completely remove rows with missing data.

```
> na.omit(dat)
  V1   V2  V3 V4 V5
1 31 3213 313 64 63
2 31 3213 313 64 63
3 31 3213 313 64 63
4 31 3213 313 64 63
5 31 3213 313 64 63
```

Comment: If you remove the advice to replace `NA` with -999 I will upvote.  This is a good answer, but R has great mechanisms to deal with missing data.  Using -999 is a workaround for systems that don't know how to deal with NA.

Comment: @Andrie - while replacing NA with -999 is just one way, I added it because question asks for it.

Comment: It's still poor advice. Better advice would be to show the OP how to use `na.omit()` and the other variations of `foo(..., rm.na=TRUE)` etc.

Comment: na.omit() removes incomplete rows, which is not a user may want. Having said that it's good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for this but what about if I don't know the width of the columns? The data I am sent often comes in any shapes or form. I would be happy to replace with NA, I know what to do from there.

Comment: @SnowFrog You may have to build a library of sorts that describes the different file format you get. Or simply open the file in a file editor and count the widths, as I did with your example. Your other option is to read the file line by line and work out some heuristic to guess where the column breaks are, but that will most likely be rather complicated.

Comment: I had voted up the the comment by @geektrader Jan 24 9:50 because it showed that they were specifically answering my question. However, I see that since the replacement by -999 has been removed. While R may have other ways to deal with NA and it is indeed good practice to specify, the question specifically asked for -999. There was a good reason for that, namely that I then wrote the data with -999 to file which was then read by another programming language.